# apple push notification - design of the server part

Tags: ios, notifications, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have seen many tutorials and opinions on that - I have developed a simple script that will send batches of notifications to Apple servers, and I crontask it every 5 seconds. (it's php so far, should be improved soon).

This way, the code is simple, and if 1 batch is larger, it will not delay the next batch. It also allows to run on multiple servers to dispatch faster and solves any concurrency issues

However, I am not clear about Apple tolerance to the fact that I open/close a socket with them every 5 seconds... In sandbox mode, it works perfectly.

Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach:
- batch all in some data-structure (I don't know about PHP, but in Objective-C this would be a NSArray containing instances of some custom NotificationClass or NSDictionaries).
- if you have either A) batched up more then X notifications you send them through, or B) waited a certain time (e.g. 5 seconds).

Depending on what you use the push notifications for you can adjust these variables. A chat app for example want them to be sent immediately, while some daily messaging app would probably be OK with sending them all at once each hour or so.

Also, Apple's words on opening connections:

> You may establish multiple connections to the same gateway or to
>   multiple gateway instances. If you need to send a large number of push
>   notifications, spread them out over connections to several different
>   gateways. This improves performance compared to using a single
>   connection: it lets you send the push notifications faster, and it
>   lets APNs deliver them faster.
>
> **Keep your connections with APNs open across multiple notifications;
>   don’t repeatedly open and close connections. APNs treats rapid
>   connection and disconnection as a denial-of-service attack.** You should
>   leave a connection open unless you know it will be idle for an
>   extended period of time—for example, if you only send notifications to
>   your users once a day it is ok to use a new connection each day.

See here for official docs ([Best practies for Managing Connections](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW6)).

Comment: Actually, all the batch of notifications are already stored in a database on a server, and I expect several 1000 per 5 seconds to be dispatched. I am just wondering if 5secs if a DOS for apple..

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that you simply leave the connection open between the batches.
In fact, Apple recommends you create multiple connections, so you can divide the 1000 over maybe five or ten or so connections. You could have some connection manager in your code that controls the lifetime of the connections: if no messages have been send trough for x amount of time, shut it down. If some piece of client-code requests a connection, this manager either creates a new one, or returns one that is not currently being used to send data through. The client of this manager should be prepared to not receive a connection, and the connection manager should in turn notify clients about the availability of connections.

Lots of possibilities in terms of architecture, but the main point it is better to leave a connection open and idle for some time, then to open and close them many times.

Comment: I don't think it's considered a good practice in this site for the same user to post two answers to the same questions, unless those answers offer completely different approaches to answer the question. You should have just edited the original answer with the additional content.

Comment: Sorry man, will try to not make the same mistake again. My apologies.

Comment: Ok Thanks Joride for this advice - I will have to work on a php file that stays up and running with a single connexion !